# Detectar el cambio de valor de una variable php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una duda:

¿Cómo es posible saber cuando una variable en php cambia de valor en un ciclo while?

Tengo una consulta que hago a una BD en la cual me trae varios datos, entre ellos me trae el número de día transcurrido.

Luego arrojo los datos mediante un ciclo while:

```
while ($row_h=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado4)){

    $cel_b = $letter_h.$cel_hrango;
    //$row_h['momento'] es el valor de la consulta de días puede tener valores 55,55,55,55,55,56,56,56,56,56,57,57,57,57,57,58
    $momento_h = intval($row_h['momento']);
    if($momento != intval($row_h['momento'])){
    //Hacer muchas cosas uju!
    }
}
```

¿Cómo hago para que se detecte ese cambio de variable y pueda entrar al IF?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la variable a la que te refieres?

Comment: Hola, no me queda muy claro a que te refieres con "cambio de variable"

Comment: `$row_h['momento']` es la variable que cambia donde la asigno a `$momento_h` @PedroPrada

Comment: @Cesar es "Cambio de valor" `$momento_h` de esta varibale que se le asigna lo que tiene `$row_h['momento']` puse un comentario donde puede tener varios valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con este código:

```
$previo = NULL;
while ($row_h=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado4)){
    $cel_b = $letter_h.$cel_hrango;
    $momento_h = intval($row_h['momento']);

    if ($momento_h !== $previo) {
        //Hacer muchas cosas uju!    
    }

    $previo = $momento_h;
}
```

Es importante usar un comparador que compare no solamente el valor, sino también el tipo de dato (`!==`).

Comment: Si, de hecho la comparación del tipo de dato es importante en este ciclo. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

A la variable `$momento_h` le tienes que asignar el valor después del `if` ya que si lo haces antes siempre tendrá el mismo valor que la variable con la que la quieres comparar. Y debes inicializarla antes del `while` para que no te de error.

```
$momento_h="";
while ($row_h=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado4)){
        $cel_b = $letter_h.$cel_hrango;
        //$row_h['momento'] es el valor de la consulta de días puede tener valores 55,55,55,55,55,56,56,56,56,56,57,57,57,57,57,58

        if($momento_h != intval($row_h['momento'])){
        //Hacer muchas cosas uju!
        }
        $momento_h = intval($row_h['momento']);
    }
```

Obviamente en la primera iteración del `while` las dos variables serán diferentes por lo que se podría poner otra condición si fuera necesario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, también tu respuesta me sirvió.