# Problemas con optimización de ciclo While y Función mail de PHP

Tags: php, sql, mail

El caso es el siguiente, tengo un sistema PHP que utiliza conexión de Base de Datos a SQL Server, la base de datos que se maneja tiene una gran cantidad de datos, por lo que el proceso de consulta viene pesado.

El sistema en si cumple con su función pero el detalle es el siguiente: Tengo unas instrucciones para construir un mensaje para luego enviarlo a través de la función `mail()` de PHP, esta función la tengo adentro de un `while`, y dicho ciclo se cumple según la cantidad de destinatarios que se hayan seleccionado.

El cuerpo del mencionado mensaje esta siendo construido por un `while` que esta adentro del `while` que mencione antes, (se que no es la mejor practica) ya que la consulta tiene unos registros que necesitan concatenarse hasta que cambie el ID del registro, por ejemplo:

tengo una consulta que resulta de la siguiente forma:

ID | mail | Concepto | Mensaje |

Entonce supongamos que en el resultado tengo lo siguiente:

---

Fila 01 = ID=1, mail = david@dominio.com, Concepto = 8888, Mensaje = Bicicleta

Fila 02 = ID=1, mail = david@dominio.com, Concepto = 7777, Mensaje = Moto

Fila 03 = ID=1, mail = david@dominio.com, Concepto = 9999, Mensaje = Monociclo

---

Fila 04 = ID=2, mail = patricia@dominio.com, Concepto = 8888, Mensaje = Bicicleta

Fila 05 = ID=2, mail = patricia@dominio.com, Concepto = 5555, Mensaje = Triciclo

Fila 06 = ID=2, mail = patricia@dominio.com, Concepto = 9999, Mensaje = Monociclo

---

En un principio había hecho una primera consulta para obtener el ID y el mail ya que son datos que constantemente se repiten, entonces use el primer `while` con ese SQL como parámetro, después de eso hacia la consulta para que me diera los conceptos y los mensajes a través del ID, que en este caso seria algo como:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, mail FROM mitabla";
$query = sqlsrv_query(...); /*Todo eso de los parámetros de conexión*/
...
/*Aquí el while*/

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){

$mensaje = "Hola ".$row['mail'];

  /*Aquí ejecuto mi otro SQL para obtener el cuerpo del mensaje*/
  $sql2 = "SELECT concepto, mensaje FROM mitabla 
           WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'";

  $query2 = sqlsrv_query(...);
  while($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query2)){

    /*Entonces aqui construia el cuerpo tranquilamente*/
    $mensaje .= "Concepto: ".$row2['concepto']." - ".$row2['mensaje'];

  }
/*Envio del correo*/
mail($row['mail'], 'Correo', $mensaje);

}
```

Lo que quisiera es optimizar dicho proceso y no tener un `while` encerrado en el otro porque es una mala practica ya que se conecta muchas veces a la base de datos cuando con una sola conexión puedo obtener todos los datos, solo que no se como haría para concatenar el cuerpo, ya que como verán este cuerpo varia según el ID del registro.

Otra cosa que también esta sucediendo es que cuando usamos 100 destinatarios, este proceso cumple con 97 o con 95 o con 98 o con los 100 envios, por favor si alguien me puede explicar por que sucede esto se lo agradecería mucho, ya que he pensado que es por el tema de que el proceso no esta optimizado pero francamente no estoy seguro de eso. Básicamente mi problema se origina es por la variabilidad que hay con el tema de los envíos, ya que el navegador se pone muy lento cuando ejecutamos este modulo con gran cantidad de destinos y asumimos que no se envían todos debido a que el proceso no esta optimizado pero como dije anteriormente no estamos seguros al 100%.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te recomiendo editar y centrar a un problema específico el título de tu pregunta, pues así como lo pones es basado en opiniones y eso sería motivo de cierre

Comment: Listo amigo, tienes mucha razon, gracias.

Comment: hacer una sola consulta ( un join de tablas ), recorrer el resultado, crear los mails en un array, por último recorrer el array de mails y hacer el envío de cada uno. ( separas el fetch del send )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de realizar varias pruebas he conseguido la formula para optimizar este proceso. Conseguí la respuesta guiándome de esta pregunta ([Click aquí para ver](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142157/detectar-el-cambio-de-valor-de-una-variable-php))

Basicamente este seria el codigo...

```
$previo = NULL;
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){

    if ($row['id'] != $previo) {
        //Instrucciones    
    }else{
        //Otras Instrucciones
    }

    $previo = $row['id'];
}
```

Así podemos evitar usar un ciclo iterativo adentro del otro.